# angular: Calling el.setAttribute results in an error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, renderer, setattribute

I'm trying to set a new attribute (defined as **'data-num'**) within each element (labeled as `el`) referring to **[ngDN]** (as an instance of the directive `NgDNDirective`).

### Concept:

The code below explains how `NgDNDirective` is intended to work:

1. TS part:

   ```
   import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

   @Directive({
     selector: '[ngDN]'
   })
   export class NgDNDirective {

     private dn: number = -1

     @Input() set ngDN(dn: number) {
       this.dn = dn
     }

     @Input() set EV(ref: {ev: EventEmitter<void>}) {
       ref.ev.subscribe(() => {
         console.log('data-num:', this.dn)
         this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef, 'data-num', this.dn.toString())
       })
     }

     constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
                 private renderer: Renderer2) {}

   }

   @Directive({
     selector: '[ngLoop]'
   })
   export class NgLoopDirective {

     @Input() set ngLoop(iter_count: number) {
       this.container.clear()
       for (let i=0; i<iter_count; i++) {
         let ee: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>()
         let ref = {ev: ev}
         let ev = this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {index: i, ev: ref})
         ev.detectChanges()
         ee.emit()
       }
     }

     constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>,
                 private container: ViewContainerRef) {}

   }
   ```
2. HTML part:

   ```
   <ng-template [ngLoop]="10" let-i="index" let-ref="ev">
     <a href="#" [ngDN]="i" [EV]="ref"></a>
   </ng-template>
   ```

### Problem:

After running the test, the console shows me the following information:

> data-num: 0
>
> ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function Stack trace:
>   ../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js/DefaultDomRenderer2.prototype.setAttribute@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:78803:13
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:66266:9
>   set/<@http://localhost:8888/main.bundle.js:869:17
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56260:36
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1558:13
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1505:17
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1445:9
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1409:13
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1153:17
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56234:54
>   set@http://localhost:8888/main.bundle.js:928:17
>   updateProp@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:63715:5
>   checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:63407:19
>   checkAndUpdateNodeInline@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64945:17
>   checkAndUpdateNode@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64884:16
>   debugCheckAndUpdateNode@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65745:38
>   debugCheckDirectivesFn@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65686:13
>   View_HomeComponent_4/<@ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.ngfactory.js:121:9
>   debugUpdateDirectives@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65671:12
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64851:5
>   callViewAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65216:21
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65174:17
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64852:5
>   callViewAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65216:21
>   execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65148:13
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64857:5
>   callViewAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65216:21
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65174:17
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64852:5
>   callViewAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65216:21
>   execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65148:13
>   checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:64857:5
>   callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:66071:39
>   debugCheckAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:65611:12
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:62782:9
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:57420:58
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:57420:13
>   next/<@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:57297:100
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:2936:17
>   onInvoke@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56503:24
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:2935:17
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:2686:24
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56434:54
>   next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:57297:70
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56248:36
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1558:13
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1505:17
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1445:9
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1409:13
>   ../../../../rxjs/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:1153:17
>   ../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56234:54
>   checkStable@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56468:13
>   onLeave@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56547:5
>   onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8888/vendor.bundle.js:56497:17
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:2968:17
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:2736:28
>   ../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:3043:24
>   invokeTask@http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:3915:9
>   globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:8888/polyfills.bundle.js:3933:17

This means that the injected instance of Renderer2 from `NgLoopDirective` to `NgDNDirective`, comes without `setAttribute` method. Why does this occur?

### Further informations:

> ng -v
>       _                      _                 ____ _     **_    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     /** | |   | *|   / △ \ | '* \ / _`| | | | |/ _` | '**|   | |   | |    | |  /**  \| | | | (| | |*| | |
>   (*| | |      | |***| |*** | | /*/   __| |*|__, |__,*|*|__,*|*|
>   ____|_____|***|
>                  |***/ @angular/cli: 1.2.3 node: 6.11.0 os: linux x64 @angular/animations: 4.3.3 @angular/common: 4.3.3 @angular/compiler:
>   4.3.3 @angular/core: 4.3.3 @angular/forms: 4.3.3 @angular/http: 4.3.3 @angular/platform-browser: 4.3.3 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic:
>   4.3.3 @angular/router: 4.3.3 @angular/cli: 1.2.3 @angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.3 @angular/language-service: 4.3.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Renderer2#setAttribute(el, name, value)` ends up calling `el.setAttribute(name, value)`. What the error says is that the argument passed as `el` does not have a `setAttribute()` method. And that is because it is an [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) instance.

You should be passing the actual DOM element:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, ...)
```

Comment: Note that the name of the renderer property is `renderer` not `renderer2` - Please consider updating it within the answer, thanks.

Comment: Updated. Thx for the heads up.

Comment: what is the reason to use `Rendrer2` instead of `this.hostElement.nativeElement.setAttribute()` ?

Comment: The main benefit is that this way it is easier to run the doce non-DOM rendering targets (e.g. when rendering on the server or rendering in NativeScript).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the 'ngDN' attribute as the selector for your directive,
but you are also trying to set the value of that attribute to the value of your loop index.

Using the attribute as the selector should be fine, but you shouldn't be trying to set it's value. Your Directive has an input named 'ngDN':

```
  private dn: number = -1

  @Input() set ngDN(dn: number) {
    this.dn = dn
  }
```

You should probably change this to:

```
@Input() dn: number = -1;
```

and then change your template to:

```
<ng-template [ngLoop]="10" let-i="index" let-ref="ev">
  <a href="#" ngDN [dn]="i" [EV]="ref"></a>
</ng-template>
```