# angular unit test cases: el.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: angular

I am running the Unit test cases where I am getting error of el.setAttribute is not a function.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Tried many solution available online but no success.

[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-setattribute-is-not-a-function#:~:text=The%20%22setAttribute%20is%20not%20a,should%20use%20attr()%20instead](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-setattribute-is-not-a-function#:%7E:text=The%20%22setAttribute%20is%20not%20a,should%20use%20attr()%20instead)).

[angular: Calling el.setAttribute results in an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259054/angular-calling-el-setattribute-results-in-an-error)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35994